# Same perimeter / different area of rectangle - how can the resulting curve be described

Tags: geometry

I was playing around a little with the area of rectangles - just out of curiosity.
As a fact, when changing the area of a rectangle with the same perimeter, the maximum size will be reached when it is a square (I am sure there are better mathematical terms for this, but math in school is too long ago).
I created some data in Excel:

```
100 * 0 = 0
99 * 1 = 98
98 * 2 = 196
...
50 * 50 = 2500
...
```

This results in the blue curve:

[image]

There is an obvious similarity to a sinus, so I put that on top of it in orange. But obviously, it is not the same. I am just wondering if the resulting - blue - line is related to something else. Or if it is just a "coincidence" that it is similar.

Thank you!

Comment: The blue curve will be of the form $A = W\cdot L = W \cdot (P/2 - W)=(P/2)W - W^2$, where $A$ is the area, $W$ the width, $L$ the length, and $P$ the (fixed) perimeter.  So it's a parabola.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x$ and $y$ be the length and width of the rectangle.  Then, for constant perimeter, we have the equation
$$2x+2y = C \implies x+y = C/2,$$
where $C$ is the perimeter (in your case, $C = 200$).
The area of the rectangle as a function of $x$ is
$$A(x) = xy = x(C/2-x) = C/2 x - x^2.$$
So, the curve you are plotting is a parabola, which can look similar to a sinusoid.

Comment: In his case $C=200$.

Comment: corrected.  Thanks.